Animating a field of arrows according to a preloaded data set
I am trying to animate a vector field for which there is no analytic mathematical description. I already managed to draw such a field of arrows (see pic attached) by importing the data as a mesh grid with additional attributes to describe the rotation of each instanced arrow, which I applied using geometry nodes. Basically, for each vertex of the grid, I added a size-3 vector attribute describing the rotation. Now, I would like to animate this vector field. For each vertex, I would now have a list L of size-3 vectors describing the rotation of the arrow at each frame (so rotation L[f] at frame f), but I don't know how to pass this list to blender in an efficient way so that it can perform the rotations. I am open to any suggestions, whether geo-node or bpy based.
Thanks a lot!


Is this list an "existing" list of "desired" values? Or can it be randomized? (It's quite easy to have the randomized version in geometry nodes)

Solution for random fields
If you can accept random fields, it's pretty easy to do in geometry nodes like this:

Nodes


Yeah sadly I would like to show a very specific animation, which cannot be solved analytically so I cannot use math nodes to create a function of time.

Ok your answer actually gave me a hint! I think the best way to do it is to convert my rotation data to a video file so that I can pass it as a video texture and get control of the frame this way!

Great idea. You can use a png image sequence (better than video as a video would slightly change your data due to compression codecs) - @MartinGuillot

Good remark! I'm not familiar with png sequences, do you mean something like a .gif or something else entirely?

@MartinGuillot, many png files (one per frame), named sequentially, like "img_0001", "img_0002", ...
